# Simulink: Syntax error

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a syntax error in the following equation:

```
((Cs+Cf)*u(1)/Cf-Cs*u(2)/Cf)*(1/(1+(Cs+Cf)/(Cf*(10^(u0/20)))))*(1-exp(-(pi*f1*(10^9)/(fs*10^6))*(Cf/(Cs+Cf)+1/(10^(u0/20)))))
```

Uppercase/lowercase checked, they are ok. What could be the problem?

Comment: I guess parhethesis

Comment: If I counted well, it seems they are also ok.

Comment: What exactly is the error message? Read tips on creating a [MCVE]

Comment: It is written:
The expression: 'expression from above' in 'the name of the block' has a syntax error.
Thanks, I will take a look.

Comment: Are you using [*Interpreted MATLAB Function*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/interpretedmatlabfunction.html)?

Comment: Is that a problem? Not recommended?

Comment: See the answer. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1):

As [mentioned](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/interpretedmatlabfunction.html#f7-891286) in the documentation of [*Interpreted MATLAB Function*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/interpretedmatlabfunction.html),

> The Interpreted MATLAB Function block accepts one real or complex
>   input of type double ...

Here you're using *multiple inputs* which are `Cs`, `Cf`, `u0`, `u`, `f1` and `fs`.

---

**How to solve it?**

**Solution-1**:  **Using [Interpreted MATLAB Function block](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/interpretedmatlabfunction.html)**

One way to deal with this problem would be to concatenate all the input matrices into a single matrix and use its indices to represent each value in the equation.

e.g; if you have:

```
u=[1 5];   u0=5;   Cs=1;   Cf=1;   f1=1;   fs=20;
```

Concatenate them into a single matrix in your workspace. Something like the following would do:

```
new=[u, u0, Cs, Cf, f1, fs];  
%It could be different depending on the dimensions of these 
%variables that you actually have
```

then use the following equation according to the indices of `new` in the *Interpreted MATLAB Function block*:

```
((new(4)+new(5))*u(1)/new(5)-new(4)*u(2)/new(5))*(1/(1+(new(4)+new(5))/(new(5)*(10^(new(3)/20)))))*(1-exp(-(pi*new(6)*(10^9)/(new(7)*10^6))*(new(5)/(new(4)+new(5))+1/(10^(new(3)/20)))))
```

---

**Solution-2**:  **Using [MATLAB Function block](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html)**

You can also use the [*MATLAB Function block*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) in which you *can* use multiple inputs. For your case, write the following code in it:

```
function y = foo(u,u0,Cs,Cf,f1,fs)
y = ((Cs+Cf)*u(1)/Cf-Cs*u(2)/Cf)*(1/(1+(Cs+Cf)/(Cf*(10^(u0/20)))))* ...
    (1-exp(-(pi*f1*(10^9)/(fs*10^6))*(Cf/(Cs+Cf)+1/(10^(u0/20)))));
```

and connect *[Constant](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/constant.html) blocks* with its inputs and give the values of the constants equal to the respective variables that you want to use.